# How do you install SeaBIOS on an Acer Chromebook 11 c720p-2600?

Tags: bootloader, chromebook, chromeos

I have tried multiple times to install SeaBIOS to an Acer Chromebook 11 c720p-2600. I have also failed multiple times. Can anyone tell me how to install SeaBIOS to the Chromebook? I want Ubuntu on my Chromebook, and I do not want to install custom firmware that is not known (such as the one from Mr.Chromebox.tech, so please do not suggest it. I have screwed up a fair number of Chromebooks with his custom firmware, so I am sorry if that is what you were planning to do.)

Comment: Have you tried anything on your own that you might wanna show us?

Comment: I just edited my question, to show you what I have tried. Mr.Chromebox.tech only works for some Chromebooks, and the Acers that I have used broke because of it, unfortunately.

Comment: How is this Ubuntu-related?

Comment: It is not. I was intending to use SaeBIOS to install Ubuntu, if possible, however.

Comment: How to Install Seabios and Ubuntu on a Acer Chromebook:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1408916/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-22-04-desktop-on-an-acer-chromebook-cb3-431-from-a-usb-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SeaBIOS is an open source firmware that is used primarily in virtual machines such as with tools like QEMU.  It is not a BIOS replacement for the firmware for your machine.