# How do I install Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop on an Acer Chromebook CB3-431 from a USB contining an etched image?

Tags: 22.04

I have an Acer Chromebook CB3-431 that has reached it's end of life date.  I would like to install Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 on it.  I have etched the image file (Balen) to a USB stick.

Can I install from that USB stick and if so, specifically how do I do it.

Any Help most welcome.

Comment: Not a good idea, at least for newbies. (1) it needs a special firmware and then if you manage to boot and install (2) some devices may not work namely the sound ( https://www.reddit.com/r/chromeos/comments/b7l25j/installing_ubuntu_on_acer_chromebook_14_cb3431_no/ )

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Ubuntu on an Intel/AMD Chromebook (Google Pixelbook 2017)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1468964/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-an-intel-amd-chromebook-google-pixelbook-2017)

Answer (score 0):

I just did this (Oct 2023). Ubuntu 22 on an Acer CB3-131 series Model N15Q10. I played around with different distros, and I am very happy with a minimal Ubuntu, and it runs decently on the Acer CB3 Chromebook hardware (in my case 2GB RAM, 16GB storage).

Process should be same for the CB3-431. I also resolved the CB3 sound (hardware) issue as well (long tone).

Enable boot from USB in Developer Mode shell command, remove the write protect screw, install the SeaBIOS, install your Linux OS.

Enable Developer Mode

**esc key + refresh key + power key, then ctrl + d key** then Enter to turn off OS verification. Chromebook will reboot and require setup.

Shell Command

**ctrl + alt + t key**

To allow USB boot

```
sudo crossystem dev_boot_usb=1 dev_boot_legacy=1
```

**Do not install seabios until you remove the write protection screw.** Your screw location may be different, but here is [mine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R0KQwr6WQHc).

Install SeaBIOS

```
cd
rm -f flash_chromebook_rom.sh
curl -L -O https://johnlewis.ie/flash_chromebook_rom.sh
sudo -E bash flash_chromebook_rom.sh
```

(Edited) Alternatively, if you want to forgo a BIOS and do UEFI firmware instead:

```
cd; curl -LO mrchromebox.tech/firmware-util.sh && sudo bash firmware-util.sh
```

Install OS

Insert the USB device. Restart. Hit **esc** key at screen prompt for boot options, select to boot from the USB thumbdrive or USB SDcard reader containing OS media. Complete OS Installation. Done.

On mine, I reset all the F keys (except for screen brightness) to function like they used to in ChromeOS (Settings/keyboard/shortcuts). There were a bunch of other tweaks i did as well (like "quiet splash" which basically hides all the startup boot code on the screen), I just don't remember them all.

Keep in mind that the 'Super' key on the Chromebook is the search key, located between left shift and left tab (at least that's how it is on mine).

Hide boot code: sudo nano /etc/default/grub

find GRUB_CMDLINE and edit:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="console=ttyS0"
```

To resolve the audio issue: sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf, at bottom add

```
# Enables sof debug mode, resolves cb3 hardware audio long tone

options snd_sof sof_debug=1
```

**For those like me that install the SeaBIOS, then install the UEFI firmware, here is an easy way to fix the EFI grub boot...**

**Repaired my Ubuntu OS grub EFI using [unetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/) and [USB boot repair](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/boot-repair-disk-64bit.iso/download). Super easy. booted it up, and it fixed it for me.**

I managed to get size down so i have around 2GB free. Most of the apps I use are web based- except for DOSBOX, CUPS (for my Cannon wifi printer), and Chromium. I created a bunch of Chromium shortcuts in the "Show Applications" drawer, and moved some to the desktop folder. Free Microsoft (365) Office (Word, Excel, Powerpoint, Outlook), free Google Office apps, Gmail, Keep, Dropbox, Drive, OneDrive, etc. Even Tubi (basically like free Netflix- movies and tv). I may add free Spotify and free Pandora Radio later, and perhaps even Google Meet as well for video chat.

**Chrome browser>more tools> create shortcut**, puts the app right on Ubunbtu without snap, and without storage space usage, then I just move it to the dock, or desktop folder (like you see in the pics).

Basically i just turned my no longer supported Chromebook into a Ubuntubook that is supported. 16GB only really leaves enough space for the OS though, so much like a Chromebook, i had to set it up as a cloud based pc, and otherwise use external USB storage.

[Acer Chromebook CB3 Ubuntu 22](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfeSV.jpg)

https://i.imgur.com/VzjFJbd.png

https://i.imgur.com/aqs7FOg.png

https://i.imgur.com/AdL6GrH.png

https://i.imgur.com/NzvU52q.png

Comment: This script (https://johnlewis.ie) is outdated and does not support newer chromebooks. You can use https://mrchromebox.tech/#home instead

Comment: i just did it last month (Oct 2023) on my Intel Acer CB3. johnlewis.ie SeaBIOS worked fine for me. The Acer CB3 is an older, no longer Google supported, Chromebook.